# How to import Firebase v9 Auth Error object (JS SDK)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Here's where I need it:

```
      try {
        await updatePassword(user, password);
      } catch (e) {
        if (e instanceof AuthError) {
          setErrorMessage(e.message);
        }
      }
```

The reason it's failing is because `AuthError` is just an interface exported from the 'firebase/auth' module not an actual Error subclass.

Comment: What isn't working about the code you shared? Is there any error message?

Comment: This is not valid JS because AuthError is a Typescript interface not a JS class. I want to import the error subclass that AuthError inherits from.

Comment: This line: https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/blob/b33a455769df5ad66926bc8755294b2b277e3c5b/auth/useCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword.ts#L39 fails in typescript. because the default e in catch is of type `unknown`. isinstanceof tells the TS compiler that the error is for sure of type of AuthError.